# how to call variable name in array of object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is my code in react.

```
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState<CountriesEntityData | null>({
    id: '',
    name: '',
    regions: [
      {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        districts: [
          {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            locations: [{ id: '', city: '', division: '', street: '' }],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
```

I try this code in resolving this problem

```
value?.regions?.name
```

can anyone give me tutorial link in dealing in this kind of situation thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Which variable name? Where you wanna use it? You wanna use a variable while defining a state or what? Why have you written this code `value?.regions?.name` ?

Comment: Do you expect to actually call `setValue(null)`? If not  and with using an initial value, why even allow `null` (`CountriesEntityData | null`)? It just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna use the first element you can do:

```
let name = value?.regions?.[0]?.name;
```

If if you wanna search the object based on an id, then I think there is a find function on the array which you can use like that:

```
let name = value?.regions?.find((elm) => elm.id == 'myId')?.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

a `regions` in `value` is `array`.
and not answer `value?.regions?.name` .
because `regions` contains `objects` and `objects` contain property ```name'''

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of problems, simply you can use `log` and see your variable in console

```
  console.log(your const);
```

then by looking at your console, easily you can see how to address your array to get your desired result.

Now assuming that you want to extract the nested names in the object,
for two arrays inside each other, you should use two `MAP` which are nested.
this can give you the idea:

```
{ListOfData.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    {item.content.map((c, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <h3>{c.title}</h3>
        <h3>{c.description}</h3>
        <hr />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```